# How do I get Android Studio to display the value of a calculation in a textView

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android programming and I'm having issues programming a basic app. The app is supposed to calculate the mark needed on a course exam in order to obtain a certain mark in a course (this is not a homework problem and is just something that I'm working on). Specifically, I'm having trouble finding a way to display the result of the calculation in a textView widget. I have posted my code below. On a side note, my app also crashes immediately on startup, so if you find anything suspicious, that would really help out. Thanks!

Update: Thanks to hai hack, my app opens up properly now. However, it still crashes after I click the button. I have update my code and logcat to show the changes made

MainActivity:

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Button;

 import static com.managergmail.time.finite.finitemanager02.R.id.calculateButton;
 import static com.managergmail.time.finite.finitemanager02.R.id.textViewExamMarkNeeded;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   Button buttonCalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculate);
    buttonCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText currentGradeInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.currentGradeInput);
            float currentGradeValue = Float.valueOf(currentGradeInput.getText().toString());
            //obtaining value of currentGrade inputted by the user and converting to float

            EditText desiredGradeInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.desiredGradeInput);
            float desiredGradeValue = Float.valueOf(desiredGradeInput.getText().toString());
            //obtaining value of currentGrade inputted by the user and converting to float

            EditText examWeightInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.examWeightInput);
            float examWeightValue = Float.valueOf(examWeightInput.getText().toString());
            //obtaining value of currentGrade inputted by the user and converting to float

            float currentGradeWeight = 100-examWeightValue;
            //calculating current grade weight

            final float examMarkNeededValue;
            examMarkNeededValue= ((100*desiredGradeValue)-currentGradeValue*currentGradeWeight)/examWeightValue;
            textViewExamMarkNeeded.setText((Float.toString(examMarkNeededValue)));
        }
    });
}
}
```

xml code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text="@string/input_the_weighting_of_your_exam"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.078"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.356" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text="@string/input_your_desired_grade"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.078"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.19" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewExamMarkNeeded"
    android:layout_width="265dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.662"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.378" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text="@string/input_your_current_grade"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.073"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.034"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/currentGradeInput"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView3" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/desiredGradeInput"
    android:layout_width="133dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/examWeightInput"
    android:layout_marginEnd="33dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/currentGradeInput"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/examWeightInput"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/calculateButton"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/desiredGradeInput"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/desiredGradeInput"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCalculate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:text="@string/calculate"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewExamMarkNeeded"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textViewExamMarkNeeded"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1" />
```

logcat

```
12-17 21:14:05.840 18312-18312/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.managergmail.time.finite.finitemanager02, PID: 18312
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.managergmail.time.finite.finitemanager02/com.managergmail.time.finite.finitemanager02.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2581)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1502)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""
                                                   at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                   at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:308)
                                                   at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:306)
                                                   at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Float.java:343)
                                                   at com.managergmail.time.finite.finitemanager02.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6280)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1116)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1502) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

Comment: Where did your app happen crash? Could you include the error logcat?

Comment: I added the logcat. It appears that there was an issue with the float values but I'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: so you want to do the calculation dynamically or the calculation should only be done on clicking the submit button?

Comment: I guess the calculation should be done after the submit button is clicked

Comment: fine now the code is working or you still facing the same issue

Comment: I added the things that Hai Hack suggested and now my app opens up properly. However, my app crashes after I click the button. I also get a "cannot resolve symbol 'textViewExamMarkNeeded". I will update my original post to include the added code

Comment: can you share what error you're facing now

Comment: previously you had that number format exception because you cannot convert a empty string to float. To overcome the above you should use **addTextChangedListener**

Comment: I'm now facing an "int cannot be dereferenced" error message in my gradle and the build fails. I will continue to look for my mistakes. Where would I use the addTextChangedListener that you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your editext

```
    final EditText currentGradeInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.currentGradeInput);


   currentGradeInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            currentGradeValue = Float.valueOf(currentGradeInput.getText().toString());
       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

       }
   });
```

Above code will work perfectly without throwing any number format exception.

Comment: is this code supposed to be placed in the OnCreate()? Also, are there any import declarations I need for this? Thanks again for your help

Comment: also, in my java file, the setText method is highlighted in red and it says "cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String)'

Comment: settext can only be applied for editext and textview. I think you might have used setext for other variable like float or int types

Comment: the current issue is this line of code `textViewExamMarkNeeded.setText((Float.toString(examMarkNeededValue)));`

Comment: Declare **textViewExamMarkNeeded** like you did for edittext

Comment: If you find the answer useful. Kindly  mark it as useful. so that in future it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `examMarkNeededValue` is computed to `null`. So I would suggest you use:

`String.valueOf(examMarkNeededValue)`

instead of

`Float.toString(examMarkNeededValue)`

Because in case of `Float.toString`, if the instance is `null`, then `NullPointerException` is thrown, but in that case `String.valueOf` would return a string `"null"`.
The computation is null because you haven't used event listener on the button.

Comment: I tried to change to the `String.valueOf(examMarkNeededValue)` but I still got a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

From the beginning, your EditTexts had no value, so using `Float.valueOf(currentGradeInput.getText().toString())` in onCreate() method meant that you were converting a empty string "" to float number. That's impossible making your app to crash.

In this case, you should have a Submit button in your app to get the input values and convert them. Inside onCreate(), add:

```
Button btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btn_button);   
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        float desiredGradeValue = Float.valueOf(desiredGradeInput.getText().toString());
                        float examWeightValue = Float.valueOf(examWeightInput.getText().toString());
                        textViewExamMarkNeeded.setText((Float.toString(examMarkNeededValue)));
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Hi sorry I'm very new to android programming. Where would I place this code in my java file? Also, would I have to import any new things or have to create a new button in the xml for this to work? Thanks again!

Comment: @SeanW Yes, you must create new Submit button in Xml, and move all lines where you get the input values `Float.valueOf` inside the method `onClick()`. See my editted answer.